# Nodejs -- req and res arguments of callback function in createServer()

Tags: node.js

[image]

I am confused about 'parser = this' mean, because I can't find there is calling about this function, so what 'this' mean in this native code?

This is the link of github: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v0.12/lib/_http_common.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The value of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) depends on how the function is called. [It appears that it is supposed to be called as a method of an `HTTPParser` instance](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2332fc944581689ef9fb93a899093827133e5f5b/lib/_http_common.js#L168-L183):

```
var parsers = new FreeList('parsers', 1000, function() {
  var parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST);
  // ^^^ parser object is created

  parser._headers = [];
  parser._url = '';

  parser[kOnHeaders] = parserOnHeaders;
  parser[kOnHeadersComplete] = parserOnHeadersComplete;
  parser[kOnBody] = parserOnBody;
  parser[kOnMessageComplete] = parserOnMessageComplete;
  // ^^^ function is assigned to parser instance

  return parser;
});
```

Therefore we can assume that `this` will most likely refer to an instance of `HTTPParser`.

Comment: But firstly, why it will call the parserOnMessageComplete function, where it call that function;                                                                         
secondly, what 'new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST)'  and 'parser[kOnMessageComplete]' mean, where to find the native code of instance, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's so that `parser` has scope when the code is called asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I find the basic c language, these are called by itself when you put into httpParse free list 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbrjL.png)
This is the address of github: https://github.com/joyent/http-parser